# Setting a minimum target version of .NET Core

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-core, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

I am getting ready to release a new WPF application, built with VS2022 and .NET 6.0.1. I sent a beta copy to a beta tester, who found a couple bugs. He has .NET 6.0.1 desktop on his computer. I fixed the bugs and sent him a new beta a couple days ago. The program wouldn't run, and I found in the event viewer that the app was looking for Presentation Framework 6.0.2. Unknown to me, my development machine had installed .NET 6.0.2 in the interim, and the simple rebuilding of my app, now requires .NET 6.0.2 to run. The situation was easily resolved by installing .NET 6.0.2 on the client computer.

My concern is, I need to be able to fix bugs after release, without suddenly making everyone upgrade to, say, .NET 6.0.3 or something later. I would like my app to allow for .NET 6.0.1 or later. I've seen people talk about global.json settings, but I'm under the impression that that's only for web apps.

Could someone please tell me what setting I need to make, and where, in my project files (I actually have one executable and five DLLs) so that I won't have this issue if I make a future build against .NET 6.0.3 or 6.0.4 or whatever?

EDIT: I have these lines in my project file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows10.0.17763.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>disable</Nullable>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    <UseWindowsForms>False</UseWindowsForms>
    <ApplicationIcon>Images\TestIcon.ico</ApplicationIcon>
    <ApplicationManifest>app.manifest</ApplicationManifest>
    <Version>1.23.6.0</Version>
    <Platforms>AnyCPU;x86</Platforms>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Thank you so much,

Comment: Desktop apps like your should use self-contained deployment, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#publish-self-contained

Comment: @LexLi I wouldn't say "should" but "could" is appropriate. It does massively increase the size of the deployment though.

Comment: @DavidG This question itself clearly indicates the necessity. For any machine you don't own and cannot manage its .NET Core runtime installation, it makes no sense to use framework dependent deployment. The size increase is a fair price to pay, as you won't get both.

Comment: @LexLi There are other options though, it is possible to build installers that pull down frameworks too. All I'm saying is you can't absolutely say "should" here.

Comment: I really don't want to use self-contained deployment, though I will investigate that further in case it's more appealing that it was the last time I looked into it. The executable clearly has the .NET version that it's built with, stored inside it *somewhere*; you'd think there would be a simple way to put something like

<BuildFrameworkVersion=6.0.2/>

(or something like that) in the project file.